# Get specific row of an Excel sheet

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I'm trying to read only the columns 1,3,6 and 7 for all rows. I tried like this but it doesn't work.

```
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);

        $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Prefixes');
        $i =2;
        foreach($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row){

            $dest = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $i)->getValue();
            $code = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $i)->getValue();

            $price = trim($sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6,$i)->getCalculatedValue());
            $date = date('Y-m-d',PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(7,$i)->getCalculatedValue()));

            $rateSheet[] = array($dest,$code,$price,$date);         
            $i++;

        }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "doesn't work"? Does it display any error messages? Does it return the wrong data? Does it set your server on fire? And why are you using a rowIterator and then addressing individual cells directly?

Comment: counting might be starting from 0, keep that in mind

Comment: it's like an infinite loop and my roof is on fire :P. It's not correct to iterate for each row and get the value of each row? How I can do it then?

Comment: And that's error message :  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted

Comment: What Mark (the creator of PHPExcel) means you load the entire row each loop and within the loop you get the data again with another method.  You don't need to use a `rowIterator()` if you use `getCellByColumnAndRow`. A `for()` loop with the `getHighestRow()` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If it might help someone this is the right way :

```
$rateSheet=array();
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);
    if($file=="519340.xls"){
        echo "</br>OK</br>";
        $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Prefixes');
        $i =2;
        $highestRow=$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1)->getHighestRow();
        echo $highestRow;
        for($j=0;$j<$highestRow;$j++){
            $dest = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $i)->getValue();
            $code = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $i)->getValue();           
            $price = trim($sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5,$i)->getCalculatedValue());
            $date = date('Y-m-d',PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6,$i)->getCalculatedValue()));          
            $rateSheet[] = array($dest,$code,$price,$date);             
            $i++;               
        }
        return $rateSheet;
```